# Pandas: Set A Row's Values Based on Row Above it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `temp_df`, which has a bunch of columns including 7 lag columns (`t-1, t-2, ..., t-7`).

```
             t-1      t-2   t-3      t-4    t-5     t-6      t-7
date                            
2010-01-08  81.0    104.0   124.0   5.0     113.0   34.0    101.0
2010-01-09  67.0    81.0    104.0   124.0   5.0     113.0   34.0
2010-01-10  89.0    67.0    81.0    104.0   124.0   5.0     113.0
2010-01-11  132.0   89.0    67.0    81.0    104.0   124.0   5.0
2010-01-12  105.0   132.0   89.0    67.0    81.0    104.0   124.0
```

I want to change the second row's lag columns to be the same as those of the first row.  So ideally, it would look like this after the change:

```
             t-1      t-2   t-3      t-4    t-5     t-6      t-7
date                            
2010-01-08  81.0    104.0   124.0   5.0     113.0   34.0    101.0
2010-01-09  81.0    104.0   124.0   5.0     113.0   34.0    101.0
2010-01-10  89.0    67.0    81.0    104.0   124.0   5.0     113.0
2010-01-11  132.0   89.0    67.0    81.0    104.0   124.0   5.0
2010-01-12  105.0   132.0   89.0    67.0    81.0    104.0   124.0
```

I've tried this:

```
lag_cols = ["t-" + str(i) for i in range(1,8)]
temp_df.iloc[1][lag_cols] = temp_df.iloc[0][lag_cols]
```

But it results in no change to `temp_df`.

Any idea why that is / how to achieve this change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to `loc`'d slices like this -

```
df.loc[df.index[1], lag_cols] = df.loc[df.index[0], lag_cols]

df
              t-1    t-2    t-3    t-4    t-5    t-6    t-7
date                                                       
2010-01-08   81.0  104.0  124.0    5.0  113.0   34.0  101.0
2010-01-09   81.0  104.0  124.0    5.0  113.0   34.0  101.0
2010-01-10   89.0   67.0   81.0  104.0  124.0    5.0  113.0
2010-01-11  132.0   89.0   67.0   81.0  104.0  124.0    5.0
2010-01-12  105.0  132.0   89.0   67.0   81.0  104.0  124.0
```

Note that `loc` only accepts labels, so you'll need to jump through a couple of hoops, but quite doable.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Ah, well I don't want to have it match all of the columns for the row above, just `lag_columns`.  Maybe `df.iloc[1, lag_cols] = df.iloc[0, lag_cols]`?

Comment: @COLDSPEED Hmm, just tried that and I get `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: @bclayman What about `df.iloc[1, lag_cols] = df.iloc[0, lag_cols].values`?